Error status 4 meaning? - causing BLE disconnection in onClientConnectionState()
I'm programming a simple app with Kotlin and Android Studio to connect with an ESP332 peripheral. Currently, I'm running into issues with disconnecting immediately after scanning and connecting to GATT. When I test my app with a virtual peripheral (LightBlue app), everything is fine, it's just when I test with the actual ESP32, which runs code that advertises and receives notifications.
I've used Logcat to get the following message:
onClientConnectionState() - status=4 clientIf=9 device=58:CF:79:D9:12:C2
2024-03-17 03:38:45.683 12680-12701 BluetoothGattCallback   com.example.motorsapp                I
However, I've looked up the error code documentation and status 4 does not exist, so I'm unsure what is going wrong. Has anybody experienced this before?

elcome to Stack Overflow. https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Files/Specification/HTML/Core-54/out/en/architecture,-mixing,-and-conventions/controller-error-codes.html#UUID-b9560149-67c7-01e7-3df2-d3cb1f879dcf
